# How to create an Office add-in using React + TypseScript in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, office-js

If I go to create a new project in Visual Studio, the add-in template it generates is based on JavaScript and uses JQuery framework, but I'd like to create an add-in using React (so I can use Fabric UI for react) and Typescript, is there an option for doing that?

I know that if I can use Visual Code and Node to create a project like this, 'yo office' has the option to generate a template for many different types of add-ins, but I found no option for this in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Office Tools in Visual Studio do not have that option, but it's a great idea! Please go to [Office Developer User Voice](https://office365.uservoice.com/) and suggest it.